# Receiving an array of integers from a server in C to a client in Java

Tags: java, c, sockets, network-programming

How do I receive an array of integers from a server program written in C, to a client program written in Java?

So I send a number to a server and the server should return me an array of the divisors for that number. Here's my piece of code from the server, in C:

```
void deservire_client(int c) {
  // serving the client
  int nr, i=2, nrDiv=0, sirDiv[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  recv(c, &nr, sizeof(nr), MSG_WAITALL);
  nr = ntohs(nr);
  while ( i <= nr/2){
            if ( nr%i == 0){
                sirDiv[nrDiv]=i;
                nrDiv+=1;
            }
            i+=1;
        }
  send(c, &sirDiv, sizeof(sirDiv), 0);
  close(c);
```

So I tested it out and the array of divisors is being created in the server file. As in, it takes the number I send it, and executes the program correctly, ending up with an array of the number's divisors. I then send the reference to my array back to my client program, in Java. However, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, since once I input a number in the client, nothing happens.

Here's what I'm doing in my Java client program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);
            int nr = readUnsignedShort("nr = ", reader);
            byte[] arr = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            writeIntegersToSocket(nr,  socket);
            readArrayFromSocket(socket);
}


private static void readArrayFromSocket(Socket c) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream socketIn = new DataInputStream(c.getInputStream());
        int i;
        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
        byte[] data = new byte[10];
        dis.readFully(data);
        for(i=0; i < data.length; i++)
            System.out.println(" " + data[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You are not closing your sockets on the java side for starters. And then you are posting only subsets of your code. Nobody told you yet about providing a minimal viable complete example!?

Comment: I posted a complete example before and it was pretty big and I only solved part of the issues there, since I also had a connection issue prior to this. Also, I am closing the sockets in Java, but this is just a snippet of the full code. I only posted this part because this is where, in my opinion, the problem occurs.

Comment: You know, the point is **minimal** but **complete** example. And hint: most likely, alone the process of creating a really minimal piece of example code might help you solve your problem. And you know: you created that bug in your code; so, if you are so convinced that must be in the code you are showing here ... why cant you spot it yourself? Not meant to be rude - but you dont trust your code; so what makes your trust your assessment about which part of the code is wrong?

Comment: please keep in mind, that on server and client machines,byte ordering of integers might be different (big endian vs. little endian), and that the size of an integer on different systems (32bit/64bit) and languages (java, c, ...) might be different. So sending integers as  raw byte data can easily fail. Consider transferring your integers to a architecture-independent representation, for example as string values. This introduces conversion overhead and increases data transfer, but will prevent some nasty bugs which are hard to trace.